# Updating slider position in a custom TabBar when device orientation changes in iOS with UIKit

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uistackview

I'm trying to create a custom TabBar with a slider that has the same width as the buttons inside it. The slider should change color and position based on the index of the button pressed within the TabBar. My current implementation is shown below, but the problem is that when the device rotates or the app resizes, the slider gets stuck in the wrong position. I've attempted several approaches to solve this issue, but I'm starting to think that the entire logic behind my implementation might be flawed.

[image]

[image]

```
import UIKit

class SlidingTabBar: UIView {
    
    public var tapCallback: ((Int) -> ())?
    private let horizontalStack = UIStackView()
    private let sliderView = UIView()
    private var sliderLeftConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?
    let items : [CustomTabBarItem] = CustomTabBarItem.allCases
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder:aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: UIView.noIntrinsicMetric, height: 60)
    }
    
    private func commonInit() {
        // Set up the slider view
        sliderView.backgroundColor = items[0].color.withAlphaComponent(0.2)
        sliderView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        sliderView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addSubview(sliderView)
        
        horizontalStack.distribution = .fillEqually
        horizontalStack.alignment = .center
        horizontalStack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addSubview(horizontalStack)

        
        let pad: CGFloat = 8.0
        
        sliderLeftConstraint = sliderView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: horizontalStack.leftAnchor)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            horizontalStack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: pad),
            horizontalStack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: pad),
            horizontalStack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -pad),
            horizontalStack.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -pad),
            
            sliderLeftConstraint!,
            sliderView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: horizontalStack.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1.0 / CGFloat(items.count)),
            sliderView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: horizontalStack.heightAnchor),
            sliderView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: horizontalStack.centerYAnchor)
        ])
                
        for (index, item) in items.enumerated() {
            let itemView = createTabBarItemView(for: item)
            itemView.tag = index
            horizontalStack.addArrangedSubview(itemView)
            itemView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: horizontalStack.topAnchor).isActive = true
            itemView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: horizontalStack.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        }
        
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
        self.backgroundColor = .white
    }
    
    private func createTabBarItemView(for item: CustomTabBarItem) -> UIView {
        let itemView = UIView()
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: item.image)
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        imageView.tintColor = item == items[0] ? item.color : .gray

        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = item.title
        label.textColor = item == items[0] ? item.color : .gray
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12, weight: .semibold)
        
        let itemStackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [imageView, label])
        itemStackView.axis = .vertical
        itemStackView.alignment = .center
        itemStackView.spacing = 2
        itemStackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        itemView.addSubview(itemStackView)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            itemStackView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: itemView.centerXAnchor),
            itemStackView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: itemView.centerYAnchor),
        ])
        
        itemView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(itemTapped(_:))))
        
        return itemView
    }
    
    @objc private func itemTapped(_ recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        guard let itemStackView = recognizer.view,
              let indexItem = horizontalStack.arrangedSubviews.firstIndex(of: itemStackView) else { return }
        
        tapCallback?(indexItem)
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
            self.sliderView.backgroundColor = self.items[indexItem].color.withAlphaComponent(0.2)
            self.sliderLeftConstraint?.constant = CGFloat(indexItem) * self.sliderView.bounds.width
            
            self.layoutIfNeeded()
            
            self.horizontalStack.arrangedSubviews.enumerated().forEach { (index, view) in
                if let imageView = (view.subviews.first as? UIStackView)?.arrangedSubviews.first as? UIImageView,
                   let label = (view.subviews.first as? UIStackView)?.arrangedSubviews.last as? UILabel {
                    imageView.tintColor = index == indexItem ? self.items[index].color : .gray
                    label.textColor = index == indexItem ? self.items[index].color : .gray
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I also created an `enum`, CustomTabBarItem:

```
enum CustomTabBarItem: CaseIterable {
    case home, search, messages, profile

    var image: UIImage? {
        switch self {
        case .home: return UIImage(systemName: "house")
        case .search: return UIImage(systemName: "magnifyingglass")
        case .messages: return UIImage(systemName: "message")
        case .profile: return UIImage(systemName: "person")
        }
    }

    var title: String {
        switch self {
        case .home: return "Home"
        case .search: return "Search"
        case .messages: return "Messages"
        case .profile: return "Profile"
        }
    }

    var color: UIColor {
        switch self {
        case .home: return .orange
        case .search: return .blue
        case .messages: return .green
        case .profile: return .red
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to update the parent view when the device rotates or a better approach altogether to achieve what I'm trying to accomplish?

Comment: One possible solution is to change how the horizontal position of the `sliderView` is specified. Instead of using a constraint for its leading edge, constrain its horizontal centre to the horizontal centre of the selected tab item. You will need to create your tab items before you can add this constraint. And you will need to keep the constraint in a property so that you can remove the old constraint and create a new one each time the selected tab changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid any need for "calculations" ...

Instead of using `sliderLeftConstraint`, let's change that to:

```
private var sliderCenterConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?
```

Instead of controlling the `sliderView` width with:

```
sliderView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: horizontalStack.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1.0 / CGFloat(items.count)),
```

Constrain its width to the first "item" (your stack view is set to `.fillEqually` so we can rely on just the first arranged subview).

So, in you `for (index, item) in items.enumerated() {` loop:

```
if index == 0 {
    sliderView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: itemView.widthAnchor).isActive = true

    // and constrain sliderView centerX to itemView centerX
    sliderCenterConstraint = sliderView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: itemView.centerXAnchor)
    sliderCenterConstraint?.isActive = true
}
```

then in `itemTapped(...)` handler, position `sliderView` like this:

```
self.sliderCenterConstraint?.isActive = false
self.sliderCenterConstraint = self.sliderView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.horizontalStack.arrangedSubviews[indexItem].centerXAnchor)
self.sliderCenterConstraint?.isActive = true
```

Now, when the view changes width (such as on device rotation), `sliderView` constraints will still be valid and it will be sized and positioned automatically.

Here's a modification of your `SlidingTabBar` class - see the comments for a few additional changes

```
class SlidingTabBar: UIView {
    
    public var tapCallback: ((Int) -> ())?
    private let horizontalStack = UIStackView()
    private let sliderView = UIView()
    private var sliderCenterConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?
    let items : [CustomTabBarItem] = CustomTabBarItem.allCases
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder:aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: UIView.noIntrinsicMetric, height: 60)
    }
    
    private func commonInit() {
        // Set up the slider view
        sliderView.backgroundColor = items[0].color.withAlphaComponent(0.2)
        sliderView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        sliderView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addSubview(sliderView)
        
        horizontalStack.distribution = .fillEqually
        
        // leave this at the default (.fill) and you don't need to constrain top/bottom of itemViews
        //horizontalStack.alignment = .center
        
        horizontalStack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addSubview(horizontalStack)
        
        
        let pad: CGFloat = 8.0
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            horizontalStack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: pad),
            horizontalStack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: pad),
            horizontalStack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -pad),
            horizontalStack.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -pad),
            
            sliderView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: horizontalStack.heightAnchor),
            sliderView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: horizontalStack.centerYAnchor)
        ])
        
        for (index, item) in items.enumerated() {
            let itemView = createTabBarItemView(for: item)
            itemView.tag = index
            horizontalStack.addArrangedSubview(itemView)
            
            if index == 0 {
                sliderView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: itemView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
                sliderCenterConstraint = sliderView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: itemView.centerXAnchor)
                sliderCenterConstraint?.isActive = true
            }
            
            // don't need these
            //itemView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: horizontalStack.topAnchor).isActive = true
            //itemView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: horizontalStack.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        }
        
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
        self.backgroundColor = .white
    }
    
    private func createTabBarItemView(for item: CustomTabBarItem) -> UIView {
        let itemView = UIView()
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: item.image)
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        imageView.tintColor = item == items[0] ? item.color : .gray
        
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = item.title
        label.textColor = item == items[0] ? item.color : .gray
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12, weight: .semibold)
        
        let itemStackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [imageView, label])
        itemStackView.axis = .vertical
        itemStackView.alignment = .center
        itemStackView.spacing = 2
        itemStackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        itemView.addSubview(itemStackView)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            itemStackView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: itemView.centerXAnchor),
            itemStackView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: itemView.centerYAnchor),
        ])
        
        itemView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(itemTapped(_:))))
        
        return itemView
    }
    
    @objc private func itemTapped(_ recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        guard let itemStackView = recognizer.view,
              let indexItem = horizontalStack.arrangedSubviews.firstIndex(of: itemStackView) else { return }
        
        tapCallback?(indexItem)
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
            self.sliderView.backgroundColor = self.items[indexItem].color.withAlphaComponent(0.2)
            
            // re-make the sliderCenterConstraint, setting it to the "selected" view
            self.sliderCenterConstraint?.isActive = false
            self.sliderCenterConstraint = self.sliderView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.horizontalStack.arrangedSubviews[indexItem].centerXAnchor)
            self.sliderCenterConstraint?.isActive = true
            
            self.layoutIfNeeded()
            
            self.horizontalStack.arrangedSubviews.enumerated().forEach { (index, view) in
                if let imageView = (view.subviews.first as? UIStackView)?.arrangedSubviews.first as? UIImageView,
                   let label = (view.subviews.first as? UIStackView)?.arrangedSubviews.last as? UILabel {
                    imageView.tintColor = index == indexItem ? self.items[index].color : .gray
                    label.textColor = index == indexItem ? self.items[index].color : .gray
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```